# How can we remove/modify the Namespaces from the CRX explorer

Tags: aem, crx

How can we remove/modify the Namespaces from the CRX explorer(//host:port/crx/explorer/nodetypes/index.jsp)
Also observed that upon manual deletion of the entries which are registered at path **"crx-quickstart\repository\repository\namespaces" ns_reg.properties, ns_idx.properties** files are not affecting the changes immediately. I need to restart the CQ to take the effect of deleted namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Solution can be found here: https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com/t5/adobe-experience-manager/how-can-i-delete-a-namespace-created-in-crx/td-p/225163

From the page:

```
Follow the below steps :

1) Login to here : <ip>:<port>/crx/explorer/browser/index.jsp (Content Explorer)

2) Go to this path : /jcr:system/rep:namespaces

3) Search for the namespaces you want to delete in the properties – and then delete.

4) Save All.

Check in Namespaces - and the NS deleted should not be there. No restart required.
```